# Show a duplicate value on seperate excel spreadsheet

Tags: duplicate, cells

I have an two excel spreadsheets.  One of the sheets is a summation of what is on the other sheet.  I need to have a cell on the summation sheet that will tell me if i have a duplicate (more than 3 times) in a single row on the other data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If your raw data is in column A of sheet1 and your summation in column A of sheet 2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!A1)>3,"More than 3","3 or less")
```

Then drag down so that the reference Sheet2!A1 autofills to include all the values.

If you mean the raw data is all in a row, then a simple modification will make this work e.g. if the raw data is all on the first row:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$1:$1,Sheet2!A1)>3,"More than 3","3 or less")
```

and drag down similarly.